# How can you refresh an embedded site?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, page-refresh

I am at a loss for how to go about refreshing an embedded page using **vanilla** JavaScript. I have tried the following, but it does not seem to work

```html
<html>
  <iframe src="https://flowlab.io/game/play/1987226" width="100px" height="100px" id="HI" />
  <script>
    function refreshIFrame() {
      var x = document.getElementById("HI");
      x.contentWindow.location.reload();
    }

    function sleep(milliseconds) {
      const date = Date.now();
      let currentDate = null;
      do {
        currentDate = Date.now();
      } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
    }
    refreshIFrame();
    sleep(1000);

  </script>

</html>
```

Comment: Sorry to focus on a side issue, but you should definitely **NOT** be writing a custom sleep function; your do-while loop will exhaust your browser's memory and CPU. You should be using asynchronous programming. [This question and answer shows](//stackoverflow.com/q/6909692/14363557) you should probably replace your sleep function and everything after it with `setInterval(refreshIFrame, 1000)`.

Comment: Oh! I didn't know that, but thanks. I didn't even know setIntreval was a thing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish with this, but the following will work. Use setInterval to do the timing. I added a cache buster for good measure.

```
    <iframe src="https://flowlab.io/game/play/1987226" style="width:1000px;height:600px;" id="HI"></iframe>
<script>
  function refreshIFrame() {
    console.log('Refresh');
    var x = document.getElementById("HI");
    //to help prevent cached reload, add a cache buster
    const cb = new Date().getTime();
    x.contentWindow.location.href = "https://flowlab.io/game/play/1987226?cb=" + cb;
  }

  setInterval(function() {
    refreshIFrame();
  }, 1000)

</script>
```